# Zend Service Amazon doesn't work

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-web-services

I created the AMAZON API KEY. This is my code:

```
$query = new Zend_Service_Amazon_Query('AMAZON_API_KEY',
                                       'US',
                                       'AMAZON_SECRET_KEY');
$query->category('Books')->Keywords('PHP');
$results = $query->search();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result->Title . '<br />';
}
```

But it doesn't print anything. I also tried to use this patch, but it still doesn't work:
http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12046

I'm sure that the api key is correct because I don't have a 500 error.

What can I do?

Comment: have you done a var_dump($result) to see if you are getting anything?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon requires an associate tag for all API queries now, see https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/…:

The changes, described below, will help us continue to provide you with relevant and useful features to advertise Amazon products. The following changes to the API will take effect on November 1, 2011:

Associate Tag will be a required and verified input parameter in all requests to the API

The sample code at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/… does not work any more:

```
$query = new Zend_Service_Amazon_Query('AMAZON_API_KEY', 'US', 'AMAZON_SECRET_KEY');    $query->category('Books')->Keywords('PHP'); $results = $query->search(); foreach ($results as $result) { echo $result->Title . ''; }
```

A first step would be to update the documentation to reflect this working usage:

```
$query ->category('Books') ->AssociateTag('myassociatetag-21') ->Keywords('PHP');
```

But preferably the constructor would be changed:

```
$query = new Zend_Service_Amazon_Query('AMAZON_API_KEY', 'US', 'AMAZON_SECRET_KEY', 'myassociatetag-21');
```

......